# Navigation image too short in landscape

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationbar

In my iPhone app, I've put an image sized 480 x 44 in the navigation bar, but when I change to landscape, the image becomes shorter. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make 2 different versions of the image (landscape and portrait mode) and then implement `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to select the appropriate version.

Comment: yah i'm using 320X44 for potrait and 480X44 for landscape but it shorter in landscape

Comment: It happened to me. You'll must to shorten its height too.

Answer (score 3):

The image size is reduced because the navigation bar has a different size in landscape mode and it crops the portrait one (44px height).

Should be **32** pixels in height in landscape.

Comment: thanx but 480 becomes shorter in landsacpe

Comment: Yes, the OS automatically resizes the navigation bar in landscape mode to 34px height instead of 44px in portrait. AFAIK it's not possible to change this behaviour so you'll have to change the images when the device is rotated (see Ruben answers)?

Comment: height is 32 not 34 px in landscape mode